Why is this Scala method failing to successfully call the Mediawiki API login?
Here is my Scala code:
    def login(botUN: String, botPW: String): Option[String] = {
        try {
            val s = requests.Session(verifySslCerts = false)
            val params0 = Map("action" -> "query", "meta" -> "tokens", "type" -> "login", "format" -> "json")
            val resp0 = s.get(MediawikiClient.wikiApi, params = params0)
            val loginToken = ujson.read(resp0)("query")("tokens")("logintoken").str

            val params1 = Map(
                "action" -> "login", 
                "lgname" -> botUN,
                "lgpassword" -> botPW,
                "lgtoken" -> loginToken,
                "format" -> "json")

            val resp1 = s.post(MediawikiClient.wikiApi, data = params1)
            val result = ujson.read(resp1)("login")("result").str
            println(ujson.read(resp1)("login")("reason"))
            Some(result)
        } catch {
            case e: java.util.NoSuchElementException => None
            case e: requests.RequestFailedException => None
        }
    }

This method evaluates to Some(Failed) and prints the reason Unable to continue login. Your session most likely timed out.. The version of Mediawiki is 1.39.6.
However, using the same Mediawiki API url and bot credentials with the Python script given on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login#Python is successful, with {'result': 'Success', 'lguserid': redacted, 'lgusername': 'redacted'} being returned, provided all HTTP requests are made with an additional verify = False parameter.
I have ran the Python script with full debug logging and have been unable to see anything being done that isn't also being done by the Scala requests.
I have tried manually getting and setting cookies, as well as setting all headers to be the same as the headers used in the Python script, with no difference to the outcome. My expectation was that this Scala method would function similarly to the given Python example and successfully login.

You would need to debug the HTTP Request and Response to get more details.
